# javascript reading text files from the server

Tags: javascript, text

**I'm a newb to javascript and have a problem with reading text files on the server** --

My aim is a simple site like this (below) that reads and displays data  from a file on the push of a button.

[image: basic website]

The code and (simple text data) data live on the server and can be in the same folder - just to get started, code so far (sorry, I could only do a screen shot - I had trouble positing html/js code):
[image]

Comment: In-browser JavaScript runs on the client, rather than the server, so can't access files that way (there's no file system object in the browser). You could load the file using an AJAX request, however.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest making an ajax call and read the data in. Since you are new to javascript, I would go with adding the jQuery library and using its ajax command. Also, later look into namespacing your code to keep the javascript off of the global scope but that is a separate big conversation.

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: function(data){fileData=data;},
  dataType: dataType
});
```